# ARM mode switch breaking program execution

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm

I am making an embedded system on a raspberry pi 3 B. Currently I am trying to change execution modes to set the different stacks (the user stack, the supervisor stack, the interrupt stack...). As far as I understand it should be enough to simply write the correct value to the CPSR as follows:

```
;@"================================================================"
;@ Now setup stack pointers for the different CPU operation modes.
;@"================================================================"
        ldr     sp, =0x8000 // initialize stack pointer
        mov r0, #1
        bl set_LED

        msr CPSR_c, #0xD1                  ;@ Switch to FIQ_MODE
        ldr sp, =__fiq_stack               ;@ Set the stack pointer for that mode
        msr CPSR_c, #0xD2                  ;@ Switch to IRQ_MODE
        ldr sp, =__irq_stack               ;@ Set the stack pointer for that mode
        msr CPSR_c, #0xD3                  ;@ Switch back to SRV_MODE
        ldr sp, =__svc_stack               ;@ Set the stack pointer for that mode

        mov r0, #0
        bl set_LED
```

The set_LED turns the led on for a value of 1 and off for a value of 0, After this code there is a mock OS that prints a silly message to the screen. If I try to execute this code, the led remains ON so it seems like the CPU never actually gets to execute the second led change and all I can see in my monitor is a color palette (the default one the Pi uses to indicate the VC is working). If I comment the 6 lines in the above code that are relevant to context switching, my program works fine, by that I mean that the led ends in an off state after the program reaches the final infinite loop and my monitor displays a black screen with a silly message I use for debugging (no color palette).

I would like to understand why this code is breaking program execution since all the documentation I have read seems to say this is the way to change modes and initialize the stack pointers.

Comment: Shouldn't you switch to user or system mode after you're done setting up those other stacks instead of leaving it in supervisor mode?

Comment: This has very little to do with Electronics engineering, I feel like you would get a better answer on StackOverflow or RaspberryPi.SO.